# Escape single quote in LIKE SQl Query in C# code behind

Tags: c#, sql, sqldataadapter

I have a query that looks like this.

```
SELECT [ID], [First_Name], [Last_Name], FROM [Employees] WHERE First_Name LIKE 'Jo%'
```

But this does not work on C# code behind. How do I escape the first single quote after LIKE?

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [ID], [First_Name], [Last_Name], FROM [Employees] WHERE First_Name  LIKE ' + @Search + '%'", cs);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search",tbNameSearch.Text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
 ...LIKE @Search + '%' ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement should be:

```
"SELECT [ID], [First_Name], [Last_Name], FROM [Employees] WHERE First_Name  LIKE @Search"
```

Then you can change the value of @Search:value:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search",tbNameSearch.Text + "%");
```

Comment: the double '' is how you escape quotes in sql, not in C#.  You don't need to escape single quotes in C# (which you have demonstrated).  Additionally, @Search is not a C# variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`"SELECT [ID], [First_Name], [Last_Name], FROM [Employees] WHERE First_Name  LIKE '@Search%'"`

The `%` might screw that up, I'm not sure.  Try removing the `%` first, and if the query works, add it back in to see if anything breaks.

Comment: No, that searches for a string starting with an at sign, then S, then e, then a, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell even though the `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search",tbNameSearch.Text);` should overwrite that?

Comment: parameters are not implemented via search+replace. In c#, it would be the difference between `string s = x;` and `string s = "x"; ` - completely different things

Comment: @MarcGravell Good to know, thanks.  I always did wonder how that worked.